# scipy.optimize.brute converges outside of range?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am doing a simple optimization using scipy.optimize.brute, but the values I am getting lie outside the range. I am not using a finisher.

Documentation is here: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.brute.html#scipy.optimize.brute

My code:

```
ranges = ((a/100.0, 10*a), (b/100.0, 10*b), (3.0, 50.0), (k/1000, 1000*k), (c0/10.0, 10.0*c0))
print ranges
p1 = optimize.brute(errfunc_sum_sq, ranges, Ns=2, disp=True)
print p1
```

Output:

```
((0.001, 1.0), (0.07, 70), (3.0, 50.0), (5.0000000000000004e-08, 0.05), (0.1, 10.0))
Optimization terminated successfully.
         Current function value: 33969.362280
         Iterations: 426
         Function evaluations: 724
[ 0.03307178  0.01554712  0.01630616  0.31982767  0.57099047]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: "I am not using a finisher.". In fact, you are. Looking at the function definition, it has `finish=<function fmin at 0x483ade8>`. Set `finish=None` explicitly (as stated in the manual) to ensure you stay inside the ranges. See the **Notes** section at the bottom of the documentation.

Comment: @Evert is right. See `Notes` section in the end of the same reference you linked in your question.